# Cassandra com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection$1 onConnectionException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, lagom

I am using **Cassandra 3.11.3** with **Lagom 1.4.7**. I wrote Integration test cases for Impl but facing ControlConnection Exception.
This is the test file below:

```
 class BookingServiceImplIntegrationTest extends AsyncWordSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  private val server = ServiceTest.startServer(ServiceTest.defaultSetup.withCassandra(true)) { ctx =>
    new BookingApplication(ctx) with LocalServiceLocator {
      override def additionalConfiguration: AdditionalConfiguration =
        super.additionalConfiguration ++ Configuration.from(Map(
          "cassandra-query-journal.eventual-consistency-delay" -> "0"
        ))
    }
  }

  val bookingService: BookingService = server.serviceClient.implement[BookingService]

  import server.materializer

  override def afterAll: Unit = server.stop()

  "The Booking service" should {

    "allow add bookings" in {
      for {
        created <- addBooking(BookingDetails)
        retrieved <- retrieveBookings(created)
      } yield {
        created should ===(retrieved)
      }
    }
  }

  def awaitSuccess[T](maxDuration: FiniteDuration = 10.seconds, checkEvery: FiniteDuration = 100.milliseconds)(block: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
    val checkUntil = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxDuration.toMillis

    def doCheck(): Future[T] = {
      block.recoverWith {
        case recheck if checkUntil > System.currentTimeMillis() =>
          val timeout = Promise[T]()
          server.application.actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(checkEvery) {
            timeout.completeWith(doCheck())
          }(server.executionContext)
          timeout.future
      }
    }

    doCheck()
  }
```

While running this test file I am facing an exception:
[image]

Please suggest how to resolve it!!
Thanks in advance